How to apply clip-path to svg element not the child
Originally I have this SVG


<svg viewBox="0 0 288 288">
  <circle style="fill: black;" cx="144" cy="144" r="144"></circle>
</svg>
 



I want to show a checkered alpha layer using CSS. But when applying it to the svg I have a problem when the svg is non-rectangular. In order to solve it I'm trying to use clip-path. But for some reason the same circle element that I am using for the clip-path is not matching the one in the displayed svg. How can I make these two match?


<svg viewBox="0 0 288 288" clip-path="url(#clip-path-0)">
  <defs>
<clipPath id="clip-path-0">
  <circle cx="144" cy="144" r="144"></circle>
</clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle style="fill: black;" cx="144" cy="144" r="144"></circle>
</svg>



svg {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #ebebeb 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #ebebeb 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #ebebeb 75%), linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #ebebeb 75%);
    background-size: 30px 30px;
    background-position: 0 0, 0 15px, 15px -15px, -15px 0px;
}

I can achieve the results I want with


<svg viewBox="0 0 288 288" clip-path="url(#clip-path-0)">
  <defs>
<clipPath id="clip-path-0" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
  <circle cx=".5" cy=".5" r=".5"></circle>
</clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle style="fill: red;" cx="144" cy="144" r="144"></circle>
</svg>



But I need the two circles to be identical because the circle can be anything (it could be path).

Firefox displays the two cases the same so presumably this is a Chrome bug. You could try reporting it to Chrome's bugtracker

Not sure, but why not apply the background directly to the SVG without any clip-path? SVGs have by default a transparent background. See codenpen

Not quite sure what you intended, but you should use <g> to group all the items you want to be masked. Then, apply the mask to the group, not the parent <svg>.


    <svg viewBox="0 0 288 288" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <defs>
          <style>
          svg {
              background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #ebebeb 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(-45deg, #ebebeb 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 75%, #ebebeb 75%), linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 75%, #ebebeb 75%);
              background-size: 30px 30px;
              background-position: 0 0, 0 15px, 15px -15px, -15px 0px;
          }
      </style>  
        <clipPath id="clip-path-0">
          <circle cx="144" cy="144" r="144"></circle>
        </clipPath>
     </defs>

      <g clip-path="url(#clip-path-0)">
          <circle style="fill: red;" cx="144" cy="144" r="144"></circle>
      </g>      
    </svg>




I think it's a bit difficult to understand the intention because it's out of the ordinary.
But basically I want to the css background to be masked. So the result would actually only show the red circle. And only if the circle is transparent would the checkered background be visible underneath.
